# Implementing Google Accounts' OpenID like Stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

Firstly, This question may be asked. But I could not get the information i am looking for.
I am creating a website which should take to google.com where the user enters his account information and it redirect back to my website similar to how stack over flow is doing when we click on gmail image.

I am trying to implement a website in .net.

Please list a step by step procedure to implement it or suggest some documentation to follow.
I clearly dont want other types of openID implemention where u enter the open id and pick ur open id provider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the walkthrough on dotnetopenauth.net not sufficent?

Comment: I need a google account api document but most of the documentation is about direct openid by selecting blogger or google account but it will not redirect to gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Check out below articles:

1. http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0907061
2. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx

Both has shown example using DotNetOpenAuth - The former list other library named  ExtremeSwank.

Comment: 2nd link is not working...and first is talking more generic openID implementation and want website to redirect to google.com and authorization should happen there.

Comment: Corrected the 2nd link. The first article is also with source code - step by step as requested by you. In general, once you have OpenId implementation, any OpenId provider will work with it.

Comment: thaks vinay. I will look into it.

Comment: All these links explain user providing the openid url. But i am looking at something redirect user to the open id website and user authenticates it. Thanks for the information u provided they are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used www.janrain.com and it was simple enough to do.

It also has the advantage of allowing you to use other vendors without any extra - not only gmail.

Oh, and it's free!

Comment: thanks for the support. But I dont want to use 3rd party tools i want to implement it with the api from google, yahoo, facebook etc.